# IIS 8 how to view site properties

Tags: web, iis, iis-8

I am trying to view the site properties so I can look at my extension mappings in an asp.net core app. I am trying to better understand asp.net at a more intricate or low level. I am learning about ISAPI and how it is the initial code point for an asp.net request.

Anyway when I right click on my site in IIS I do not see the properties tab. I am sure that this is related to the version of IIS that I am using, so my question is, how can I view the site properties? Or how can I get to the extension mappings?

Comment: You are probably reading an ancient IIS 5/6 book which tells about "properties tab". That's long gone, and IIS 7 and above uses a completely different management interface, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/modules/

Comment: Okay I'll dive into that in the morning. Thanks

Comment: Try not to follow old guides/books. Microsoft does have tons of articles already https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-the-iis-manager-in-iis-7-and-iis-8

Comment: Thanks a lot, I realized yesterday that I do not fully understand some of the deeper workings of asp.net, so after spending some time reading I found an old article and it was using IIS 5/6. I need to read up on the asp.net pipeline and a few other things. I will start with these articles, if you know of any others that could help, send them my way! @LexLi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iis 5 and 6 has a feature to see the site properties. after iis 7 there is no option like site properties. you can check iis site advance setting by following the below steps:

1)open iis manager

2)right-click on your site.

3)select manage website ->advance setting

[image]

Edit:

**Request Filtering**  which is used to restrict the types of HTTP requests that IIS  processes. By blocking specific HTTP requests, request filters help prevent potentially harmful requests from reaching the server. The request filter module scans incoming requests and rejects requests that are unwanted based upon the rules that you set up. and **ISAPI Filter** always runs on an IIS server, filtering every request until they find one they need to process. The ability to examine and modify both incoming and outgoing streams of data makes ISAPI filters powerful and flexible. you could refer to the below link for more detail on how to configure it in iis:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524610(v=vs.90)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525937(v=vs.90)

Comment: Thanks but this is not quite what I was looking for. I am looking more for information on request filtering, ISAPI filters etc.

Comment: @stupidQuestions please check the updated post. let me know if you still find any issue.